# How to hide measure numbers in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

In Lilypond, by default measure numbers are printed in each new line.

How to hide these numbers?

[image: bars with measure numbers]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually at the end of the [documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/snippets/rhythms#rhythms-removing-bar-numbers-from-a-score):

```
\layout {
    \context {
        \Score
        \omit BarNumber
    }
}
```